# Split cells not importing first 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, regexextract

I am using split formula:

```
=IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(" , "&U4,  "(\d)",  "$1 ,"),  ",  "))
```

It works great except if I have `0250`, it imports it across as `250`, even with the cell it's importing  from is set to `#000` and it sits in the 1st 3 cells instead of the 2nd 3rd and 4th cells

When the number is `1250` it works fine, but if it's `0250` then it comes through as `250` not `0250`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(""&A2, REPT("(.)", LEN(A2))), 
         REGEXEXTRACT( 0&A2, REPT("(.)", LEN(A2))))
```

[image]